# How to restrict the user on clicking browser back button in angular 5

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, router, angular5

I have implemented lazy loading and the routing works absolutely fine : if the user authenticates, it will route to a particular module.

Now the issue is : if a user clicks on the browser's back button, it keeps on going backward, until the login page.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue ? For instance, how can I restrict the user not to click the back button, or is it possible to route back to home page when it comes to login page ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#guard-the-admin-feature

Answer (score 3):

Angular’s router provides a feature called `Navigation Guards` that try to solve exactly that problem. You can Read more about this at following url.

[Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router)